# Angular PHP Post to MYSQL, Add String Variable

Tags: php, mysql, json, angularjs

I have the following post from my form in Angular:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
$request = json_decode($postdata);
@$id = $request->id;
@$cid = $request->cid;
@$description = $request->description;
@$type = $request->type;
@$owner = $request->owner;
@$ssamount = $request->ssamount; 
if($owner == 'spouse' && $type == 'ira')
{$exempt == 'yes'};
if(mysqli_connect_errno()) { Etc...
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to place some logic in PHP as opposed to client side.  If the two variables from the Angular JSON posted file match a criteria as shown, I want another field in the MYSQL database to be set to yes or no.  $exempt in the above.

I get no errors but it does not change the field in MYSQL.  I think the problem might be related to the structure of the decoded JSON or that I might have to add this JSON object to $postdata before decoding it.

Any ideas?  Thank you

Comment: this is failing `{$exempt == 'yes'};` for 2 reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically in your code you should replace:

```
if($owner == 'spouse' && $type == 'ira')
{$exempt == 'yes'};
```

with

```
if($owner == 'spouse' && $type == 'ira') {
    $exempt = 'yes';
}
```

The double equal sign is a comparison operator while a single equal sign is an assignment operator.

Comment: Thank you Andrew.  Sometimes debugging is like playing Where's Waldo.